# Java code snippet output explanation required

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

My code is:

```
class Foo {
  public int a=3;
  public void addFive() {
    a+=5;
    System.out.print("f ");
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  public int a=8;
  public void addFive() {
    this.a += 5;
    System.out.print("b ");
  }
}

public class TestClass {
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    Foo f = new Bar();
    f.addFive();
    System.out.println(f.a);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
b 3
```

Please explain to me, why is the output for this question "b 3" and not "b 13" since the method has been overridden?

Comment: This is a question regarding SCJP, right?

Comment: yep @PrakharMohan have you also appeared for the same??? i haven't yet...:)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot override variables in Java, hence you actually have two `a` variables - one in `Foo` and one in `Bar`. On the other hand `addFive()` method is polymorphic, thus it modifies `Bar.a` (`Bar.addFive()` is called, despite static type of `f` being `Foo`).

But in the end you access `f.a` and this reference is resolved during compilation using known type of `f`, which is `Foo`. And therefore `Foo.a` was never touched.

BTW non-final variables in Java should **never** be public.

Comment: Well, except if you have `GridBagConstraints` or similar objects. But for a beginner, **never** is an appropriate advice :)

Answer (score 19):

`F` is a reference of type `Foo`, and variables aren't polymorphic so `f.a` refers to the variable from `Foo` which is `3`

**How to verify it?**

To test this you can remove `a` variable from  `Foo` , it will give you compile time error

**Note:** Make member variable `private` and use accessors to access them

---

**Also See**

- [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Comment: To extend this answer a bit, this is one reason why it is often safer to use getters instead of accessing variables directly.

Comment: @DaveNewton please tell me something about getters? i haven't heard this before.

Comment: This issue could be quietly avoided if used a common programming practice in Java: variables must be private (only the own class can use it). After that, as said above, using getters and setters methods to access/modify it.

Comment: Dave is saying to make private fields and use `getA()` `setA()` accessor methods to access the fields

Answer (score 12):

With such a question, the SCJP exam is assessing your knowledge of what is known as *hiding*. The examiner deliberately complicated things to try to make you believe that the behavior of the program depends only on polymorphism, wich it doesn't.

Let's try to make things a bit clearer as we remove the `addFive()` method.

```
class Foo {
  public int a = 3;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  public int a = 8;
}

public class TestClass {
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    Foo f = new Bar();
    System.out.println(f.a);
  }
}
```

Now things are a bit less confusing. The `main` method declares a variable of type `Foo`, which is assigned an object of type `Bar` at runtime. This is possible since `Bar` inherits from `Foo`.The program then refers to the public field `a` of the variable of type `Foo`.

**The error here would be to believe that the same kind of concept known as *overriding* applies to class fields.** But there is no such a concept for fields: the public field `a` of class `Bar` is not *overriding* the public field `a` of class `Foo` but it does what is called *hiding*. As the name implies, it means that in the scope of the class `Bar`, `a` will refer to `Bar`'s own field which has nothing to do with `Foo`'s one. ([JLS 8.4.8 - Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf))

So, when we are writing `f.a`, which `a` are we referring to? Recall that resolution of the field `a` is done at **compile time** using the declaring type of the object `f`, which is `Foo`. As a consequence, the program prints '3'.

Now, lets add an `addFive()` method in class `Foo` and override it in class `Bar` as in the exam question. Here polymorphism applies, therefore the call `f.addFive()` is resolved using not the compile time but the runtime type of object `f`, which is `Bar`, and thus is printed 'b '.

But there is still something we must understand: why the field `a`, which was incremented by 5 units, still sticks to the value '3'? Here *hiding* is playing around. Because this is the method of class `Bar` which is called, and because in class `Bar`, every `a` refers to `Bar`'s public field `a`, this is actually the `Bar` field which is incremented.

**1) Now, one subsidiary question:** how could we access the `Bar`'s public field `a` from the `main` method? We can do that with something like:

```
System.out.println( ((Bar)f).a );
```

which force the compiler to resolve the field member `a` of `f` as `Bar`'s `a` field.

**This would print 'b 13' in our example**.

**2) Yet another question:** how could we work around *hiding* in `addFive()` method of class `Bar` to refer not to the `Bar`'s `a` field but to its superclass eponimous field ? Just adding the `super` keyword in front of the field reference does the trick:

```
public void addFive() {
  super.a += 5;
  System.out.print("b ");
}
```

**This would print 'b 8' in our example**.

Note that the initial statement

```
public void addFive() {
  this.a += 5;
  System.out.print("b ");
}
```

could be refined to

```
public void addFive() {
  a += 5;
  System.out.print("b ");
}
```

because when the compiler is resolving the field `a`, it will start to look in the closest enclosing scope from within the method `addFive()`, and find the `Bar` class instance, eliminating the need to use explicitely `this`.

But, well, `this` was probably a clue for the examinee to solve this exam question !

Comment: nice explanation Alex

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing `f.a` you will get the value of `a` from the class `Foo`. if you had called a method to get the value, e.g `getA()` then you would have gotten the value from the class `Bar`.